# PHP Recursive Function top list

Tags: php

[image]

I want make recursive function

when i search any id the id introid will show and introid will show their introid [Urdu Guide]

[image]

if i search id 45
will show result like
22
11
5
2
1

Comment: This site works best when you ask specific questions against code you have developed. So what have you attempted so far?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
   function searchID($id)   
   {
     if ($id>1) {print intval($id/2)."\n"; searchID(intval($id/2));} else return 1;
   }
   searchID(45);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you may have **tried something** and not successful with the recursion approach ... here is the solution!

```
<?php
$introid = array(0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9, 10, 10, 11, 11, 12, 12, 13, 13, 14, 14, 15, 15, 16, 16, 17, 17, 18, 18, 19, 19, 20, 20, 21, 21, 22, 22, 23, 23, 24, 24, 25, 25);
$id = range(1, count($introid));
$associative_array= array_combine($id, $introid);

function lets_recurse($id, $associative_array)
{
    if($id==1 || $id==0)
    {
        echo '';
    }
    else if(isset($associative_array[$id]))
    {
        echo $associative_array[$id].' ';
        lets_recurse($associative_array[$id], $associative_array);
    }
    else
    {
        echo '';
    }
}

lets_recurse(45, $associative_array);
?>
```